Unable to Move Deleted Files to Trash via Hadoop Web Interface
I have encountered an issue with the Hadoop-3.3.6 Web interface regarding file deletion. By default, when I delete files through the Hadoop Web interface, they are permanently removed and do not go to the Trash. However, when I use the hadoop fs -rm command in the terminal, the files correctly move to the Trash.
I have checked my core-site.xml configuration and ensured that the following property is set:
<property>
    <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
    <value>3600</value>
</property>

Despite this, the files deleted through the Web interface are not being sent to the Trash.
Does anyone know how to enable the Trash functionality in the Hadoop Web interface? Are there any additional configurations or considerations I might be missing?
Thank you for your help!

I don't think WebHDFS has such a feature
